# been getting "overload resolution failed " in object detection using open cv

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo

I am working on a project of detection  for image and videos using `yolov3` but I have an error and don't know how to debug it.after changing athe code im stuck with this

Here is the error part of the code:

```
  def write(x, batches, results):
    c1 = tuple(x[1:3].int())
    c2 = tuple(x[3:5].int())
    img = results[int(x[0])]
    cls = int(x[-1])
    label = "{0}".format(classes[cls])
    color = random.choice(colors)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1])), (int(c2[0]), int(c2[1])), color, 1)
    t_size = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1 , 1)[0]
    c2 = c1[0] + t_size[0] + 3, c1[1] + t_size[1] + 4
    cv2.rectangle(img, (int(c1[0]), int(c1[1])), (int(c2[0]), int(c2[1])), color, -1)
    cv2.putText(img, label, (c1[0], c1[1] + t_size[1] + 4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, [225,255,255], 1)
    return img
```

The error I get:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'putText'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'org'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'org'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

I am a beginer to both python and OpenCV.

Comment: c1, c2 have to be **integer** points (you're getting **floats** from the detection)

Comment: Is it right bro ive changed as per my knowledge (i edited the above thread)

Comment: You had this (c1[0], c1[1] + t_size[1] + 4). But where is c2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your currently posted code won't run for people trying to collaborate with you to find a solution. Write a simpler function which fails on `.putText()` in the same way, and share it with us. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: needs same procedure as for the rectangle() call

Comment: Bro can anyone please change the code for me since i dont know and i have to submit the project tomorrow